# Without late initialization, why can't we declare a top-level property in kotlin by onCreate?

Tags: android, kotlin

Why isn't this possible?

Declaring a top level property without using late initialization technique and assigning value to that variable in OnCreate(Bundle?)..

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var variable : Int

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        
        variable = 10
    }
}
```

Comment: What would you expect to happen if you access `variable` before `onCreate` has been run?

Comment: The `lateinit` keyword allows you to avoid initializing a property when an object is constructed.                                                                                                                        If your property is referenced before being initialized, Kotlin throws an `UninitializedPropertyAccessException` , so be sure to initialize your property as soon as possible.                                                                                                                                   If you do not want to use `lateinit`,then use `private var variable : Int = 0`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it but then you need  init block

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private var variable : Int

init {
        variable=10
    }

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    
    variable = 10
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should know that  in Kotlin, when we declare a variable we have to initialize it *with a value* or we need to assign *null*.

But if we don’t want to initialize the variable with null or any value. Rather we want to initialize it in future with a valid value, then we have to use lateinit. **Actually it is a promise to compiler that the value will be initialized in future.**.

But what you want to declare variable without `lateinit` ?

Then game changer `lazy` keyword will come.

but there is one drawback and  that is **Every lazy property is a val (immutable) property and cannot be changed once assigned.**

so is there is certain condition that your value is fix and don't want to change it the n use *lazy* keyword.

otherwise you should initialize any default value without use of **lateinit** keyword.

like , `private var number : Int = 0` or `private var name : String = ""`
and the you can change it in `onCreate()` too.